# Modifying Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file this piece of code is present:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase off
  php_flag register_globals off
  php_flag session.auto_start off
  php_value mbstring.http_input pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation off
  php_value max_execution_time 200
  php_value output_buffering 4096
  php_flag display_errors On
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1000
  php_value session_set_cookie_params 1000
  php_value session.bug_compat_42 off
  php_value session.bug_compat_warn off
  php_value session.cookie_httponly true
  Options FollowSymLinks
  Options -Indexes
  php_flag display_startup_errors off
  php_flag display_errors off
  php_flag html_errors off
  php_flag log_errors On

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS|HEAD) 
RewriteRule .* - [F]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff”
</ifModule>

Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "Deny"

RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For

<Files phperrors.log>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All
</Files>

<Files phpaccess.log>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All
</Files>

<Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|pdf)$">
  order deny,allow
  allow from all
  Satisfy All
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/content/error.php
```

And I think the code is redirecting every unwanted/suspicious URL call to error page.
I have created a sub folder inside the domain and I want to call it like this in URL:  `http://example.com/sub_folder` but it is redirecting me every time to error page (`http://example.com/content/error.php`).

How can I include the rule in the .htaccess file, that I will be able to load the sub folder's content?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, could you please do let us know which url you want to access and which one you want to block for better understanding, thank you.

Comment: I want to access this URL : `http://example.com/sub_folder` but currently it is blocked it seems.

Comment: Ok, but which urls you want to block? I mean like `http://example.com/test123`? Just provide samples of which you want to block and which you want to access, thank you.

Comment: I don't want to block any URL, just want my added folder's URL to work properly.

Comment: There is no apparent reason the mentioned URL should be “blocked” with any of what you have shown so far. The rewrite part only makes the server respond with a 403 Forbidden response, if the request method was one of the four listed there, and even then that would not be a reason to get `http://example.com/content/error.php` served instead, based on that you specified it as the ErrorDocument for _404_. (Using an absolute URL in that place is fundamentally wrong already though btw.)

Comment: Sounds more like you might actually be getting a genuine 404 response here, because the path you requested is simply not correct. Are you sure you created `sub_folder` in the web root folder of the domain? That the spelling matches what you request after _exactly_? What happens when you add a trailing slash to the URL?

Comment: @CBroe I have edited .htaccess file, this is what I got as a legacy code. Yes folder  name and path are correct, I have crossed check it so many times. After adding trailing slash too I am redirected to error page.

Comment: You have `Options -Indexes` in there, which forbids directory listing. So you might actually just be getting a genuine 403 error here(?). Have you tried to request a specific file inside that folder, and checked if that works?

Comment: Yes, I have contact.php file inside the sub-folder's folder, tried accessing it directly through URL but I am unable to access any inside files as well and redirecting to this error page.

Comment: If you rename this .htaccess to something else and then try to access `example.com/sub_folder/contact.php` does it work?